# Angular 4 - Close button does not work until data loads inside the pop-up/table

Tags: angular, typescript, popup, ag-grid

**Angular 4 - Close button does not work until data loads inside the pop-up/table.**

1. Already Pop Up is not closing after click on anywhere on the screen.
2. I'm added backdrop functionality.., So that pop-up closed only user 
     clicks on close icon.
3. But, Close icon does not work until data loads inside the pop-up/table.
   Actually I'm using ag-grid data inside that pop-up/table.

**Does anyone have an idea ..?**

***Here is my template..,***

**reg-list.component.ts**

```
 {
        headerName: "Regulations",
        cellRenderer: this.regulationsClick,
        onCellClicked: function(params) {
          console.log(params);
          const modalRef = that.modalService.show(ControlsListComponent,{class: 'gray modal-lg', keyboard: false, backdrop : 'static'});
          modalRef.content.data = params.data;
        },
        valueGetter: this.regulationsClick,
        enableRowGroup: true,
        enablePivot: true,
}


regulationsClick(params){
    if(params.data && params.data.AppCertificateMemebers.length>0){
      const Regulations:any=[];
      let regulationstring: any;
      params.data.AppCertificateMemebers.forEach((value,index) =>{
        Regulations.push(value.Certificate.name);
        params.regulationstring = Regulations.toString();
        console.log("assets", params.regulationstring);
      });
      return `<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-size: 12px">${params.regulationstring}</a>`;
    }
    else{
      console.log("checkelse");
        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any error(s) in your console?

Comment: @DavidR No,i'm not getting any errors..

Answer (score -1):

**hi, everybody thanks for your comments for this issue.**

***Finally this issue resolved by my own research.***

> please go-through the below lines...,
>
> In general a pop-up having ag-grid data inside that time close-icon
>   cannot close suddenly while loading data inside.
>
> So.,if a user can use "modal-body" as a "class" inside "div" tag it is working well.
>
> It is closing the pop-up suddenly when user clicks on the close-icon.
>
> [Note:i.e:-Bootstrap modal-popups]

### For..,further clarification please follow below code.

***reg-list.component.html***

```
 <div class="modal-body">
       <ag-grid-angular
          #agGrid
          style="height:710px;width:auto;"
          id="myGrid"
          class="ag-theme-material"
          [rowData]="Controls"
          [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
          [enableSorting]="true"
          [enableRangeSelection]="true"
          [pagination]="true"
          [enableColResize]="true"
          (rowGroupOpened)="onRowGroupOpened($event)"
          [enableFilter]="true"
          (columnRowGroupChanged)="onColumnRowGroupChanged()"
          [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
          [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
          [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
          (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"
          [rowGroupPanelShow]="rowGroupPanelShow"
          (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
      </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
```